# Type defined in template class "does not name a type"

Tags: c++, templates

I began to use templates a few weeks ago, and I'm having trouble using it.
I got this error :

Freestyle/_gl/../_convection_selective/Definitions.h:153:9: error: ‘**Node_handle**’ in    **‘Point_set** {aka struct Kd_tree_patch > >*, My_point_property_map, CGAL::Search_traits > >, const   double*, Construct_coord_iterator> > >}’ **does not name a type**

while compiling this code:

**"Definitions.h":**

```
#include "Kd_tree_patch.h"
[...]
template <class SearchTraits, class Splitter_= CGAL::Sliding_midpoint<SearchTraits>, class UseExtendedNode = CGAL::Tag_true > class Kd_tree_patch;  //forward declaration

typedef Kd_tree_patch<Search_traits> Point_set;    
typedef Point_set::Node_handle Node_handle;
```

**"Kd_tree_patch.h"**:

```
template <class SearchTraits, class Splitter_=Sliding_midpoint<SearchTraits>, class UseExtendedNode = Tag_true >
class Kd_tree_patch {
[...]
typedef Kd_tree_node<SearchTraits, Splitter, UseExtendedNode > Node;
typedef typename Compact_container<Node>::iterator Node_handle;
};
```

Why Node_handle isn't considered as a type yet ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you are missing a `typename` there (it's a dependent type)...

Comment: You started to use templates a few weeks ago? Blimey.

Comment: @NIm Do you mean : typedef typename Point_set::Node_handle Node_handle; If so, I tried that but I got the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot forward declare nested types, which means that to be able to use the nested type `Node_handle`, the template `Kd_tree_patch` must be defined *before* the typedef. Once you fix that, you will also need to instruct the compiler that it is a type through the use of `typename`:

```
typedef typename Point_set::Node_handle Node_handle;
//      ^^^^^^^^
```